# How to split string and display it in a gridview ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have denominations stored in a database(sql server 2008) column seperated by $ sign like the following

```
 1000*2=2000$500*1=500$100*0=0$50*0=0$20*0=0
```

I want to split this string and display in gridview column like :

```
1000*2=2000 
500*1=500 
100*0=0 
50*0=0 
20*0=0
```

in 1 single column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
 string val = @"1000*2=2000$500*1=500$100*0=0$50*0=0$20*0=0";
 List<string> fields = new List<string>(val.Split(new[] { '$' }));
```

you can then  assign it to the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) member of the gridview and call [DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx).

```
 gridView1.DataSource = fields;
 gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks its working.. but how to asign database column data to string val?? i mean i have(1000*2=2000$500*1=500$100*0=0$50*0=0$20*0=0) stored in database table column along with other columns.. i want to display all the colimns in gridview

Comment: @rahul please accept answer if conrad's answer solved your problem.. so that other users can also get the accepted answer is working code..

Comment: Now i have 1 column values stored in list<string> and other columns are in database. i have extracted to datatable. i want to attach both datatable and list<string> to gridview so that i will get the complete records into gridview. how can i do that

Comment: You can also make use of a `dataTable` instead of `List<string>` `dataTable.Column.Add("List"); dataTable.Rows.Add(fields);` Then define columns for the rest of the other database table columns you need. Once done then `gridView1.DataSource = dataTable;gridView1.DataBind();` My syntax might not be 100% but I'm sure you get the idea!